# 'Select by Location' algorithm using Python script in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-processing, select-by-location

Could anyone explain to me how to run the '[select by location](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#qgisselectbylocation)' algorithm in a QGIS 3.0 script? I find it really hard to understand the documentation about it. I found a lot of docs about how to write a processing script in QGIS 2.x but it doesn't seem to work like that in QGIS 3.0 anymore. 
This is what I got so far...

```
from qgis.core import *
import processing
points = QgsVectorLayer('points_layer_path')
poly = QgsVectorLayer('polygon_layer_path')
processing.run('native:selectbylocation', points, 2, poly, 0)
```

It's not much, I know, but shouldn't it work like this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the question to more clearly explain the difference you are experiencing between revs.